# Pass awk output as input to another script

Tags: linux, awk, grep

Below I have tried to extract the `pid` of a running process to check its current `ppid`

```
ps -p 1111 -o ppid = $(ps -eo pid,args | awk '/PRD_/ && /startscen\.sh/ && $8 ~ /<string>/' | awk -F" " '{print $1}')
```

My script is wrong. Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you explain the logic you are using? Give sample input and desired output so we can understand it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does

```
ps -ef |  awk '/PRD_/ && /startscen\.sh/ {print $3}'
```

give you what you want? That searchs for a process with "PRD_" and "startscen.sh" in the CMD string, and reports the PPID. If you want to run an additional ps to get info on the parent,

```
ps -p `ps -ef |  awk '/PRD_/ && /startscen\.sh/ {print $3}'`
```

Comment: Slightly tweeked your script

Comment: ps -p `ps -ef |  awk '/PRD_/ && /startscen\.sh/ {print $2}'` instead of $3, I think the right column is $2 - it is working now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To check the ppid of a particular process, you use notation like this:

```
$ ps -p 1111 -o ppid=
```

This is *close* to what you've got, but note that the equals sign is *immediately after* `ppid`, with no space.  This equals sign *is not part of an expression*, its function with the `-o` option is to specify custom headers.  With this example I've included, you're telling ps to include no header at all, so the output will be just the ppid and nothing else.  For example, try `ps -p 1 -o ppid=Hello`.

If I'm reading this correctly, the rest of your example code appears to be unrelated to your actual question, and is an attempt to collect the pid of perhaps a shell script that is running.  So ... as an addendum to this answer, my advice on this point would be to modify the shell script so that it records its own somewhere, so you don't have to rely on parsing the process table to find it.  For example, you could add something near the top of `startscen.sh` that looks like this:

```
pidfile="/var/run/`basename $0`.pid"
if [ -s "$pidfile" ]; then
    if ps "$(cat $pidfile)" >/dev/null; then
        echo "ERROR: already running, giving up." >&2
        exit 1
    fi
fi
trap "rm -f pidfile" 0 1 2 3 5 15
echo $$ > $pidfile
```

It's not perfect, but this will provide you with some protection against running the script twice at the same time, and will store the pid of the running script in a file where other pids live.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the detailed explanation. I think, what you suggested makes senses but I am operating these scripts on a production server with little access of file creation. It would be convenient to rather create temporary variables and run the scrip real time till objectives are met. However, I am trying little scripts to enable automation on failure but that would come much later. But big thanks, I shall test your code on sandbox :)